# Adding a horizontal line to a multicolumn field in a longtable

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to add a horizontal line to the top of my table using a `\cline`. My table has 7 columns, however the first row only has one cell that spans columns 3-7.

Here is a snippet of the beginning of my table:

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{3cm} | p{5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} |}
\cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{|p{4cm}|}{Deployment Semester \& Grade Level} \\
\hline
```

And here is a snippet of what is being produced:

[image: LaTeX table with problem]

As you can see, the top horizontal line is correctly covering 5 of the 7 columns, but it is starting a column 1 even though the `\cline` command specifies column 3. I don't want a horizontal line over the first two columns since the first row only has content spanning the last 5 columns.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post fragments of code only. I get the expected output: http://imgur.com/nmB5KSN

Comment: as Christian says always post code that reproduces the problem, otherwise it is very hard to help. Did you run latex again until longtable had resolved all the column widths?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That might be a possible issue but I think not the case here (the table isn't really extraordinarily wide (in my opinion))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no but (given the lack of information posted so far) it is possible that the top line is covering columns 3-7 but in a different chunk that has not yet aligned with the later row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Agreed, considering the lack of further information/more table code it might be the issue

Comment: Sorry for the poor phrasing of the question. New poster here... The problem ended up involving the table caption (which I removed before posting the code) -- I forgot to add a newline (\\) at the end of the caption and before the first row started. I added that and everything worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This small test of use of `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,longtable}

    \begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|*{5}{p{0.5cm}|}}
    \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
    & \multicolumn{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|}{Deployment Semester 
                                                            \& Grade Level} \\
    \hline
1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

gives expected result:

[image]

Due to lack of information (MWE), as is said in above comments, it is impossible to say, what is error in real case.